# Example to show that items in a strong association rule may actually be negatively correlated?

Tags: self-study, data-mining

Give a short example to show that items in a strong association rule may actually be negatively correlated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify or provide an example of what you mean by "items in a strong association rule"?

Comment: This is a exercise question in "Data mining: concepts and techniques" Chapter 5..Question 5.13 http://books.google.co.in/books?id=AfL0t-YzOrEC&lpg=PA279&ots=UvTXxV9sE7&dq=strong%20association%20rule%20may%20actually%20be%20negatively%20correlated&pg=PA279#v=onepage&q=strong%20association%20rule%20may%20actually%20be%20negatively%20correlated&f=false

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about Simpson's Paradox, the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) is actually a fairly decent one. [Here](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB125970744553071829.html) is another example.